# Php js, log out из других вкладок

Tags: php, javascript

Когда пользователь проходит авторизацию на сайте,  ему выдается SESSION_[id],  а так же Session user.  В общем по стандарту.

Есть кнопка выхода из профиля,  Ajax запрос который уничтожает сессию,  и перезагружает страницу. Так вот,  я хотел бы узнать,  что можно предпринять для того чтобы во время Выхода из профиля,  если сайт открыт и в других вкладках, то и там произошел выход. Так как на стороне сервера сделано все что надо,  и сессия уничтожена, остается только перезагрузить страницы сайта,  везде где они открыты.

Так вот,  как можно это сделать?  Кроме лонг пуллинга. Возможно как то на js,  сделать так чтобы после отправки запроса на выход,   все вкладки текущего сайта были перезагружены?

Comment: либо уведомления через сокеты, либо яаксом проверять состояние, либо в sessionStorage записывать, а на страницах цикл по нему крутить с проверкой.

Answer (score 2):

Для синхронизации вкладок удобно использовать [storage event](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-storage-event):

```
window.addEventListener('storage', sync);
function sync(event) {
    if (event.key == 'logout') {
        // Лучше не перезагружать вкладки в фоне, а манипулировать DOM.
    }
}
```